# Reducing a string by one until no user is found in AD Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a Powershell loop that will reduce a string to twenty characters and then compare that to current Active Directory users and if it exists then it will remove one character from the end and then check again.  It would keep doing this until it finds a string that isn't a current user.  This is what I have currently:

```
$uName = (Read-Host "New User Name")
if ($uName.length -gt 20) {
    $uNameSAM = $uName.SubString(0, 20)
    foreach ($uNameSAMCheck in $uNameSAM) {
    Write-Host "`nDue to length limitations shortening Name to:  $uNameSAM`n" -Foreground Red
}else {
    $uNameSAM  = $uName
}
}
```

This works well for the shortening part, but I'm not sure how to go about checking it against AD for if the inputted name already exists and if so shortening it again and checking again and so on.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Usually I would think you'd go the opposite approach, if a smaller string doesn't exist expand the string and check if it matches a current user in AD system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Riley mentions, this is kind of an unusual pattern to enforce, but don't let me stop you.

The simplest way to approach this is doing to be with some form of loop, here I think perhaps a `while` loop might be appropriate.

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt "New User Name"
if ($Username.length -gt 20) {
    $SamAccountName = $Username.SubString(0, 20)
    Write-Warning "Due to length limitations shortening Name to: $uNameSAM"
}
else {
    $SamAccountName = $Username
}

while (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq $SamAccountName") {
    $SamAccountName = $SamAccountName.Substring(0, $SamAccountName.Length - 1)
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "'$SamAccountName' is available!"
```

There are many possible approaches. This particular one makes use of the fact that you can utilise PS's native type coercions to your favour. A `while` loop (as well as `if` statements, `until` loops, etc.) is expecting a boolean result. If a cmdlet returns *any* complex object at all, it will generally be coerced to `$true`. If it returns an empty / null result, it will be coerced to `$false`.

This behaviour is a little trickier when working with base data types like integers, strings, and the like, but for working with complex objects it's a very straightforward way to ask "did this command give me *any* output". In the case of `Get-ADUser -Filter`, if the filter doesn't match a user, no output is generated.

We **don't** want to use `Get-ADUser -Identity` because that will unfortunately throw a terminating error if it doesn't find the user requested. That can be a little more annoying to code around, so I've opted for the `-Filter` method instead.

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks!